# Not getting correct output after implementing bubbleSort

Tags: java, io, bubble-sort

This program creates a file named datafile.txt and writes 100 integers created randomly into the file using text I/O.  I also implemented bubbleSort to sort the numbers in ascending order, but it's not sorting them.  Plus, the output to command line is "The sorted numbers are: [I@f72617" 100 times.  Thanks in advance.

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.Random;

   public class Lab5 {

//sort array
static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {

    for (int pass = 1; pass <= 100; pass++) {
        for (int current = 0; current < 100-pass; current++) {

            //compare element with next element
            if (array[current] > array[current + 1]) {

                //swap array[current] > & array[current + 1]
                int temp = array[current];
                array[current] = array[current + 1];
                array[current + 1] = temp;
            } //end if
        }
    }
    return array;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    //Open file to write to
    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("F:\\IT311\\datafile.txt");


    int index = 0;

    //Convert FileOutputStream into PrintStream 
    PrintStream myOutput = new PrintStream(fout);
    Random numbers = new Random();
        //Declare array
        int array[] = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
        //get the int from Random Class
        array[i] = (numbers.nextInt(100) + 1);

        myOutput.print(array[i] + " ");

        //sort numbers
        int[] sortedArray = bubbleSort(array);

        //print sorted numbers
        System.out.print("The sorted numbers are: ");
        System.out.print(sortedArray);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error, "cannot find symbol
           System.out.print(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));" on the "Arrays"

Comment: thats because its Arrays, you need to import java.util.Arrays

Comment: Thanks.  That compiled, but the numbers aren't sorted.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  They ARE sorted in cmd line, but not in the output file.

Comment: Oh, never mind.  I don't need them sorted in the output file.  Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Thats what i was wondering, i can see them sorted. You should keep int[] sortedArray = bubbleSort(array); outside the for loop. No point in calling this time and again. Just call it once to sort all the 100 elements.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    System.out.print(sortedArray);
```

use

```
for(int a : sortedArray)    
        System.out.println(a);
```

The first one is printing the address of the array. The second one will print each element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to your code, you were printing array object on each iteration. For printing an array you have iterating through it and print its each element.
Plus bubble sort is modified & additonal code is there if you want to use is just un-comment it

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab5 {

//sort array
static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {

 for (int pass = 0; pass < 100; pass++) {
     for (int current = 1; current < 100-pass; current++) {

         //compare element with next element
         if (array[current-1] > array[current ]) {

             //swap array[current] > & array[current + 1]
             int temp = array[current-1];
             array[current-1] = array[current];
             array[current ] = temp;
         } //end if
     }
 }
 return array;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

 //Open file to write to
 try {
      FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("F:\\IT311\\datafile.txt");


 int index = 0;

 //Convert FileOutputStream into PrintStream 
 PrintStream myOutput = new PrintStream(fout);
 Random numbers = new Random();

 // code begin to print random number in file and output sorted array on sysout 
     //Declare array
     int array[] = new int[100];
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
     //get the int from Random Class
     array[i] = (numbers.nextInt(100) + 1);

     myOutput.print(array[i] + " ");
     }

     //sorted array using sort function 
//     Arrays.sort(array);

     // sortred using bubble sort
     array=bubbleSort(array);

   //print sorted numbers
     System.out.print("The sorted numbers are: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
        int j = array[i];
        System.out.print(j +" " );
        }

  // code end to print random number in file and output sorted array on sysout     



//     code begin to print sorted number in file and output sorted array on sysout
     /*int array[] = new int[100];
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
     array[i] = i;
     }
     Arrays.sort(array);
     for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
        {
        int j2 = array[j];
        myOutput.print(j2  + " ");
        System.out.println(j2+" ");
        }
        */

//   code end to print sorted number in file and output sorted array on sysout
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Error opening file: " + e);
     System.exit(1);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your time and effort.  I took zerocool's suggestion, "You should keep int[] sortedArray = bubbleSort(array); outside the for loop. No point in calling this time and again. Just call it once to sort all the 100 elements."  It worked.